# Upload big files with PHP and FTP

Tags: php, curl

I need to write a script to upload big Files (~2GB+) to a server.
I don't think HTTP is the right way to do this so I want to use (S)FTP.
There are several tutorials about this (using cURL or ftp_connect) and I understand that i have to set several things in the php.ini.

But all this tutorials upload the file to a `remote` Server, what I want to do is upload it to the Server the script is running on, without having to upload the file to the Server over HTTP first.

Is this possible? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: If the file already exists on the server, why do you need to upload it?

Comment: I don't understand your second paragraph then.

Comment: Ok,I will try to explain it:
All the tutorials assume that I upload the file to my server over http and transfer it to another server over ftp.

What I want to do is upload the file on my computer to my server, over FTP.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a simple FTP transfer? Just create an FTP script: open yourserver/binary/put bigfile.dat/quit (replace the slashes with carriage returns)

Comment: Personally I would simply use an FTP Client, but my client wants a nice Website to upload his files, because it could also be used by his wife.

Comment: Seems like it is not possible to transfer a file over ftp which is not already on the server with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP *can* be the right way to upload large files. You can use `resumable.js` or similar library to split the file in "chunks" and then reassemble the file on the server.

If you decided not to go with HTTP and have shell access, I recommend you use `rsync` (with the `--partial` flag) which will do the heavy lifting for you.